# How to bulk rename files numerically with different file types in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, rename

I'm trying to bulk rename an anime with multiple video types(mkv,mp4, and ogv) which increments with (num) that corresponds to what episode that is. Problem is, if I rename both mp4 and mkv with the same filename, it will rename it with the same incremental number. For example, I am renaming episode 1 which is an mp4 and episode two which is an mkv. When bulk renamed, it will rename to episode(1).mp4 and episode(1).mkv instead of episode(1).mp4 and episode(2).mkv. I want to increment them regardless of video type.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I tried renaming the mkv files to mp4 works but it might cause the problems with the video, and this is a 200 episode anime so renaming each one of them.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give examples of the file names, especially those you are encountering issues with.You say that renaming the `mkv` files to `mp4` works, so are these file names entirely unique with regards to numbering (i.e. no `episode 1.mp4` and and `episode 1. mkv`)? Also, do they keep the same general file name structure (ex. `episode 41`, `episode 42`, etc.)?